# ggplotly mouse values while using a log-transformed color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

In the minimal example below, where the color scale is log-transformed, the `z` value displayed when hovering the mouse above the raster is also log-transformed.
This is very uninformative and I need it to be expressed in the same unit as the scale legend.

Is it possible to avoid plotly to automaticaly do this conversion?

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)

myPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))

p <- volcano %>%
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(myPalette(100)), trans="log")

ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is this, I just added the `text = paste("Value:", value)` part (which doesn't get affected by the log):

```
p <- volcano %>%
  melt() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value, text = paste("Value:", value))) + geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(myPalette(100)), trans="log")

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("Var1", "Var2", "text"))
```

Also `tooltip` to control what to show on hover.

[image]

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you!